# Conversion of integers to Roman numerals (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, roman-numerals

I understand there were many similar questions being asked on this topic. But I still have some doubts need to be clear.

```
def int_to_roman(input):

    if type(input) != type(1):
        raise TypeError, "expected integer, got %s" % type(input)
    if not 0 < input < 4000:
        raise ValueError, "Argument must be between 1 and 3999"   
    ints = (1000, 900,  500, 400, 100,  90, 50,  40, 10,  9,   5,  4,   1)
    nums = ('M',  'CM', 'D', 'CD','C', 'XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I')
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(ints)):
        count = int(input / ints[i])
        result += nums[i] * count
        input -= ints[i] * count
    return result
```

I dont really understand the code below:

```
for i in range(len(ints)):
    count = int(input / ints[i])
    result += nums[i] * count
    input -= ints[i] * count
```

Does:

```
for i in range (len(ints)):
```

it means '1000','900','800' (the integers respectively) or it means 13 (13 integers in integers)?

```
count = int(input / ints[i])
```

what does ints [i] mean?

Anyone please explain these codes? It would be best if you could show the examples (like substitute numbers and show how it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lists, `ints` and `nums` are the same length.  The loop iterates over the length of `ints`, which means that the variable `i` can access the same position of either list, matching one to the other.

If we step through the loop, `count` is assigned the integer value of the input divided by the first number in `ints`, which is 1000.  If the `input` variable is, say, 10, then 10/1000 will result in a number <1, and using `int()` on the result will cause it to assign 0 to `count`.  When 0 is multiplied by the matching string from `nums`, the assigned result is basically nothing.  Then the same amount is subtracted from `input`, which in this case leaves it unchanged.

Eventually, the loop will reach a point when the result of the division is a number >=1, so the following steps will do something.

Let's say the result of `int(input / ints[i])` is 3.  `"X" * 3` results in `"XXX"`, which is added to `result`, and the `input` is reduced by the appropriate amount, in this case 30.  So on, until the loop ends.

Comment: Glad to help.  As @GreenAsJade mentioned, remember to upvote helpful answers, and mark accepted when you feel your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the two lists are awful (`ints` and `nums`).

However, starting with the highest roman numeral (`nums[0]` = 'M'), the loop finds out how many times the value of that numeral (`ints[0]` = 1000) divides into the input value, and appends the numeral that many times to the result string.

Then it subtracts the value of that string just added to the result (`ints[0] * count`) from the input, and moves on to the next roman numeral (`nums[1]`) to repeat the process with that remainder.

Comment: Note: I answered the first question you asked, before you edited your question.  You should only ask one question in a Stack Overflow question.   If you don't know what `ints[i]` means, you don't know enough yet to ask questions at Stack Overflow: basic programming tutorials answer that sort of question.

Comment: thanks for you explanation! I know what ints [i] means just not sure how the loop works. Thanks for your advice I will work harder!

Comment: You're welcome.   If an answer has helped you at Stack Overflow, you should upvote it.   You should "accept" (by clicking the tick) the answer that best answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def romanize(number):
   n2rMap = {1000:'M', 900:'CM', 500:'D', 400:'CD', 100:'C', 90:'XC', 50:'L', 40:'XL', 10:'X', 9:'IX', 5:'V', 4:'IV', 1:'I'}
   roman = ""
   for key in n2rMap.keys():
      count = int(number / key)
      roman += n2rMap[key] * count
      number -= key * count
   return roman
```